# Bias in percentiles: what summary statistic will not be systematically different from the true value?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles

It is known that for non-symmetric distributions, sample percentiles are biased estimators. I took the Log-normal distribution as a template. I take a small sample size (say 10 samples) and estimate the sample median. I then repeat this experiment 100,000 times to get as many sample medians, each based on 10 samples. The average of these 100,000 sample medians is removed from the true median of the lognormal distribution I sampled from, as expected (the difference is the bias). However, it seems the *median* of these 100,000 medians is actually very, very close to the true median. This is demonstrated in the figure below. The black line is the true median, the purple line is the average across the 100,000 medians and the orange line is the median across the 100,000 medians. I then increase the 10 samples to 15, 20 and so on and see how the three lines behave. The purple line (mean of medians) starts off with a bias, but this bias is corrected when more samples are collected. The orange line (median of medians) on the other hand doesn't seem to ever be biased.

[image]
Code for above plot can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ryu577/5f593ff54e5460b6e9177d899b474517

So the conclusion from the simulation above is that the mean of medians is biased, but median of medians isn't (or at least, the bias there is much smaller).

I now want to repeat this for the 90th percentile. Once again, I generate 10 samples from the lognormal and find the 90th percentile this time. Then repeat 100,000 times. I then plot these 100,000 90-percentile values in a histogram. Also, I know the true 90th percentile. Unlike with the median however, I can't find any way to summarize those 100,000 sample 90-percentiles to get something that aligns with the true 90-th percentile. I tried taking their median, their 90th percentile, their 10-th percentile, their mean, etc.

So this is my question. Is there any function that takes those 100,000 sample 90-th percentiles and produces a number that isn't systematically different from the true 90-th percentile?

Comment: For any continuous distribution $X$, let $Y$ be the result of taking the largest of $9$ samples of $X$ (or the $k^{th}$ largest of $10k-1$ samples). Then the median of $Y$ will be the $90^{th}$ quantile of $X$. In other words, the medians should work…if the subsamples are of an appropriate size, and you wait long enough for convergence, which will be a long time in the case of a heavy-tailed, heavy-skewed distribution like the lognormal.